# jQuery html() working witn alert in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I am using this code :-

```
function makeDirectionTabs() {
    alert('sdfsf');
    jQuery('.adp-warnbox').remove();
    jQuery('#adp-placemark').parent().remove();
    jQuery('.adp-legal').remove();
    var i = 0;
    jQuery('#fullDirections .adp > div').each(function () {
        i = i + 1;
        alert(i + jQuery(this).html());
        directionContent = jQuery(this).html();
        jQuery('#tab' + i).append(directionContent)
    });
}
```

I got div elements in tab1 , tab2 etc.. with alert 
But when I remove alert from this code I did not get div elements in tabs Why ?

What I am leaving .. Where Am I wrong ?

Please help Me.

Main problem :-

Loop running fast and html() function is not working. When I use alert in loog then loop stay for alert and html() works.   Please tell me resoin or solution for this.

Comment: Have you checked your console? If you can alert it but not append it something must be wrong. Perhaps #tab'i' doesn't exist. Or perhaps you just don't see it because it's being appended outside your screen or something...

Comment: Use $(document).ready();

Comment: use the var to define the variable `var directionContent = jQuery(this).html();`

Comment: Please create a fiddle for this.

Comment: Can you show us the relevant sections of HTML and how/where that `makeDirectionTabs` function is called?

Answer (score 0):

Strange because cannot see any asynchronous request anywhere. But usually, you should use the index param of each loop. See if its changing anything:

```
function makeDirectionTabs() {
    jQuery('.adp-warnbox').remove();
    jQuery('#adp-placemark').parent().remove();
    jQuery('.adp-legal').remove();
    jQuery('#fullDirections .adp > div').each(function (i) {
        directionContent = jQuery(this).html();
        jQuery('#tab' + i).append(directionContent)
    });
}
```

Comment: I think these should be a wait for loop so html() function can do his work

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this helps:

```
function makeDirectionTabs() {
    alert('sdfsf');
    jQuery('.adp-warnbox').remove();
    jQuery('#adp-placemark').parent().remove();
    jQuery('.adp-legal').remove();
    var i = 0;
    var $divs = jQuery('#fullDirections .adp > div');
    for(var i=0; i < $divs.length ; i++){
        directionContent = jQuery($divs[i]).html();
        jQuery('#tab' + i).append(directionContent)
    }
}
```

Comment: :( not running , please give any other idea

Comment: Try now, I misspelled 'jquery'